Was there an issue with polymorphs in growing synthetic quartz crystals?
Today, I read an article, The Rise of The Disappearing Polymorphs, about unwanted polymorphs ruining production of various organic chemicals, such as pharmaceuticals paroxetine hydrochloride and ritonavir.
At one time, I believe, a similar issue arose in production of synthetic quartz crystals for piezoelectric electronic resonators. However, after searching my own library and the web, I could not find a specific reference to that issue. Then I thought that I might have misremembered and the issue involved Rochelle salt crystals (also piezoelectric, but used for audio pickups), but could find no such production problem, either.
Does anyone have a citation for such issues in creating crystals, where an undesired polymorph stopped production?
[My memory might be failing with age --  while I haven't seen the Curie's demo of piezoelectricity, I have met Robert Van de Graaff, a bit of a shock!]

My lab still operates (daily!) a 1962 vintage High Voltage Engineering EN tandem accelerator. Built incredibly well, older than I am (barely).

@JonCuster, when I met Van de Graaf, it was at Ion Physics corp, which I believe was HVE's competitor.

Ion Physics was a subsidiary of HVE. HVE trying to be a high tech conglomerate is ultimately what caused their downfall. High Voltage Engineering Europa managed to survive as its own entity.
